# wp_editor embed shortcode not working within my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, editor, wp-editor, embed

for my own plugin I have a create-form which includes at least two editor fields and I insert them like this

```
wp_editor('', 'dbfield');
```

The editor is shown in the form, it gets saved into the database and the output also looks like it should.
However, when I try to use the embed shortcode (for a youtube video), I only get a loading-placeholder. When I use the same embed in a default Wordpress form (new page), the embed works.

Am I missing settings that I need to embed? I thought everything is used as default when I use wp_editor without additional settings like that.

Any help would be appreciated.

I also noticed that the editor does not look exactly like the default one, it is missing the "Distraction-free writing mode" button for example. I don't need it in the plugin, but maybe it is an indicator that I do miss some default settings?

edit 1:
The file mce-view.js (wp-includes/js/) throws an error because the property "media.view.settings.post.id" is 0. So far I use the workaround to set a different (existing) post id when the property returns 0. 
But there's clearly an issue with my plugin that I need to check further.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress OEmbed should show in the editor by default.

If it doesn't, I suspect that you need to enqueue some scripts and styles on your page where you are using `wp_editor`. Eg:

`wp_enqueue_script('editor', false, false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('quicktags', false, false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('wplink', false, false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('wpdialogs-popup', false, false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_style('wp-jquery-ui-dialog', false, false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('word-count', false, false, false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload', false, false, false, true);
wp_admin_css();
wp_enqueue_script('utils', false, false, false, true);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried but it didn't seem to make a difference.
Is there any way I can debug to see which script I might be missing?

Comment: I also noticed that my editor plugin lacks 1 or 2 buttons that the "new page" editor has. I don't need those buttons but shouldn't they also show up in the plugin when they're part of the default editor configuration?